# How to immediately get NFT metadata after mint using candy machine v2?

Tags: metaplex, metadata, react

Using Candy Machine v2, Candy Machine UI and metaplex-foundation/js.

Following https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#how-to-get-nft-metadata as my basis, I am trying to get the metadata of the NFT that was just minted by the user.

```
if (status && !status.err && metadataStatus) {
      // manual update since the refresh might not detect
      // the change immediately
      let remaining = itemsRemaining - 1;
      setItemsRemaining(remaining);
      setIsActive((candyMachine.state.isActive = remaining > 0));
      candyMachine.state.isSoldOut = remaining === 0;
      setSetupTxn(undefined);
      setAlertState({
        open: true,
        message: "Congratulations! Mint succeeded!",
        severity: "success",
        hideDuration: 7000,
      });
      refreshCandyMachineState("processed");

      // CODE TO GET METADATA
      const keypair = Keypair.generate();

      const metaplex = new Metaplex(props.connection);
      metaplex.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));

      const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint(mintResult.mintPublicKey);
      console.log("NFT: ", nft);
      console.log(nft.metadata);

    }
```

The issue I run into is that the nft status is still pending, and nft.metadata is none.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to wait until the transaction has been finalized e.g. with [connection.confirmTransaction](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#confirmTransaction) before trying to read the metadata from chain.

Comment: And just know for confirmTransaction there is an open but right now: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/25955